# Table with 100% text width and columns 1 third the table width

Tags: tables, formatting

I'd like to have a table, at the end of the page, centered, with the total width of the paragraph and each of its 3 columns exactly a third of the width.

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\title{Title}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\hfill
\begin{table}[!b]{
  \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {ccc}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \vspace{3ex}A } & B \\
  \rule{1cm}{0.4pt} & \rule{1cm}{0.4pt} & \rule{1cm}{0.4pt} \\
  \scriptsize aaa & \scriptsize bbb & \scriptsize ccc
  \end{tabu}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `tabularx` for that (equal column widths):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\title{Title}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\hfill
\begin{table}[!b]
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*3{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\vspace{3ex}A} & B \\
  \rule{1cm}{0.4pt} & \rule{1cm}{0.4pt} & \rule{1cm}{0.4pt} \\
  \scriptsize aaa & \scriptsize bbb & \scriptsize ccc
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with `array`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]

\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{w{c}{\dimexpr0.33333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}} }
\multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & B \\
\rule{1cm}{0.4pt} & \rule{1cm}{0.4pt} & \rule{1cm}{0.4pt} \\
\scriptsize aaa & \scriptsize bbb & \scriptsize ccc
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that the syntax for `table` doesn't require braces around the contents (they're actually wrong).

Comment: Just to mention it: `w` is relatively new (2018) and does actually resemble the OP better than the X column because it does not act as a parbox.

Answer (score 0):

if you like to use `tabu` (not recommended, better is use `tabularx` as [TeXnician](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/124577/texnician) suggested in his answer) than you should use `X` column types:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\title{Title}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{table}[!b]
  \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {*{3}{X[c]}} % <---
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & B                                 \\[3ex]
  \rule{1cm}{0.4pt} & \rule{1cm}{0.4pt} & \rule{1cm}{0.4pt} \\
  \scriptsize aaa & \scriptsize bbb & \scriptsize ccc
  \end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

this gives:

[image]